# return a read-only pointer from the int pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have been asked in an assignment to implement IntList, which is dynamic int array list having "int *p" as its private member. After implementing all the methods (add, find, delete, etc) , I couldn't find out how to do implement a public method returning:

- Get a read-only pointer to the underlying Array.

How can I return a pointer having *p numbers, where it's content cannot be change?

Comment: Read up on the `const` keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write the code similar to this one:

```
class A {
    int *tab;

public:
    A() {
        tab = new int[3];
        tab[0] = 1;
        tab[1] = 4;
        tab[2] = 6;
    }

    const int * get() {
        return tab;
    }
};

int main() {
    A *a = new A();
    //(a->get())[0] = 2;
}
```

- Then you'd be able to see the content of the table, but changing it's value outside the class won't be possible.
- Trying to uncomment the last line will result in getting this
  error: assignment of read-only location ‘* a->A::get()’ :)

Comment: Don't forget to free tab in A's destructor or you will leak memory! Also note that the pointer to tab will dangle after A is destroyed. This should suffice: 
`~A() { delete[] tab; }`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the `const` keyword in the method signature to tell the compiler that what is being returned is constant, or nonmodifiable. Since you're returning a pointer, you're also going to have to figure out how to differentiate between "pointer that can not be modified", and "pointer to data that can not be modified", and how to specify which one you want.

Comment: I think I need the  "pointer to data that can not be modified", and trying everything atm but still I can change the methods result.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a pointer to a constant type like so

```
type const *
```

So a declaration of a member function returning a pointer to a const type looks like this

```
type const * memberfunction();
```

Replace the word type with whatever type your are returning.

What you return cannot be changed as it is const. So it cannot appear on the left hand side of an assignment operator i.e = ; and it cannot be passed into a function or method via a non const parameter unless you cast away the constsness which I wouldn't recommend in general.